# get specify word from string php codeigniter

Tags: java, php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

I have an input for search ,

i search for "res"

```
<input type="text" name="search"I/>
```

i use Like method to get search results,

```
$txt = $this -> input -> post("search");
$this -> db -> like('title', $txt);
if ($sql = $this -> db -> get('ads') -> result()) {
            $data['posts'] = $sql;

            print_r($sql);

        }
```

and get this results :

```
some text restaurant and other
some text result
my resume
```

i want to show the liked word 
extract the word from strings and remove other texts

i want this :

```
restaurant
result
resume
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the found string into an array ([explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php)) and then search this array with the given string ([preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-grep.php)) and output the found strings.

```
<?php
$searchString = "/res/";
$foundString = "some text restaurant and other";
$explode = explode(" ", $foundString);
$searched = preg_grep($searchString, $explode);

foreach($searched as $item) {
  echo $item . " ";
}
```

Comment: No problem friend :)